# Login to salesforce

Tags: rest, login

I couldn't find how to login to salesforce organisation like mavens mate does when user creates new project. I did't find any examples. Can somebody show some example? I mean login using REST API call, without Auth I think.

I will add some code:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
username: 'someusername',
password: 'somepassword',
grant_type: 'password'
});

var options = {
hostname: 'login.salesforce.com',
port: 80,
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': postData.length
}
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
res.setEncoding('utf8');
res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
});
res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.')
})
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```

So, I did't get what I expected like in [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en) for REST API. What is wrong with this code? The response of the code above: 
STATUS: 302
HEADERS: {"date":"Sun, 03 Apr 2016 04:52:11 GMT","set-cookie":["BrowserId=UxnWs1WlSPeTEXoWQRjVbA;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Thu, 02-Jun-2016 04:52:11 GMT"],"expires":"Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT","strict-transport-security":"max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains; preload","content-type":"text/html;charset=UTF-8","pragma":"no-cache","cache-control":"no-cache, no-store","location":"https://login.salesforce.com/","content-length":"0","connection":"close"}
No more data in response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Username and Password there are couple of ways I can think of

[1.Using SOAP API to Login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm)

You can use the Partner WSDL or Enterprise WSDL and that has a method to parse and use login() call

[2.Using Oauth Username and Password Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en)

Both of these flows just use username and Password the User enters to retrieve the session Id .

Update :

I see you are using a Node for this .Since you use Node.js there are lot of libraries doing authentication for you

Check below [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/salesforce-api) package

You can use [nforce](https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce) as well to this

You will create a simple connected app

```
var nforce = require('nforce');

 var org = nforce.createConnection({
 clientId: 'SOME_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID',
 clientSecret: 'SOME_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET',
 redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/oauth/_callback',
 apiVersion: 'v27.0',  // optional, defaults to current salesforce API version
  environment: 'production',  // optional, salesforce 'sandbox' or 'production', production default
  mode: 'multi' // optional, 'single' or 'multi' user mode, multi default
});
```

Then use below

```
 // multi user mode
 var oauth;
 org.authenticate({ username: 'my_test@gmail.com', password: 'mypassword'},    function(err, resp){
 // store the oauth object for this user
  if(!err) oauth = resp;
  });
```

Comment: I tried, but filed. I edited a little bit my question.

Comment: Updated the answer ,.Check if that helps

Comment: Yes. But when I use any force.com ide, I don't use any clientId or clientSecret. Right? I use only username and password. So, whate I am trying to do is to mimic login logic of any force.com ide.

Comment: You use SOAP login there.Force.com IDE uses WSDL file to generate a login method .While mordern way is to use connected app and if you need to use username and password use username-password flow

Comment: Mavens mate as I think use Node.js. I suppose they use rest api. In either way I should be able to use this too. In some way they have implemented this too. Right?

Comment: https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate?files=1

Comment: It's phython and node based and they use oauth 2 username and password flow. .

Comment: So how do they login without client id and secret?

Comment: There might be a client ID and secret used .Remember that you just need a developer instance to create a connected app with client secret and client ID. also note that connected app is org independent ...meaning you don't need separate orgs for each of your app

Comment: Yes. But my purpose is to login as mavens mate does, not as connected app. There should be some way do that.

Comment: You can use SOAP API ..write a node parser to parse the enterprise or partner WSDL. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I thought that should by something similar in REST API but I was wrong.